# JOINing a "LIST" table with a "SPAN" table

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

In Firebird, I have a table that is a "list".  It contains records like this:

```
LstRecID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
...
```

I have another table that contains various "spans".  It contains records like this:

```
  SpnRecID | BeginSpan | EndSpan 
 ----------|-----------|--------- 
  A        |         1 |       3 
  B        |         4 |       6 
  C        |         7 |       8
```

I need a list of *ALL* `LstRecID` (left most column).  In the next columns I want the `SpnRecID` of any span record that matches or falls between the span begin or end, or, blank if there is no span record with a matching or encompassing span.  Like this:

```
  LstRecID | SpnRecID 
 ----------|---------- 
         1 | A        
         2 | A        
         3 | A        
         4 | B        
         5 | B        
         6 | B        
         7 | C        
         8 | C        
         9 |          
        10 |
```

In reality, my list table contains 1.5 million records.  I thought I could simply do a `BETWEEN`, however that is proving to be incredibly slow.  I have indexes on all fields in both tables.

I need results in 750 milliseconds or less.

```
SELECT List.LstRecID, Span.SpnRecID
FROM List LEFT JOIN
     Span
     on List.LstRecID BETWEEN Span.BeginSpan and Span.EndSpan
```

The above takes about 15 minutes to run.

```
SELECT List.LstRecID, Span.SpnRecID
FROM List LEFT JOIN
     Span
     on List.LstRecID = ANY (SELECT List.LstRecID 
                             where List.LstRecID BETWEEN Span.BeginSpan and Span.EndSpan)
```

The above takes about 15 minutes to run.

There must be a better way to display a list with encompassing spans that will operate faster than this.  Do you have any suggestions?  That is my question.

Comment: Notice there are TWO timings in any SELECT: the time to deliver FIRST row and the time to deliver LAST row. Given 1,5 rows you have, and most of them reside on HDD, I have doubts you really can get `in 750 milliseconds or less` even the simple `select * from list`. First row - sure. all the rows (last row, fetch-all command) - hardly so

Comment: do you have an index on `spans (BeginSpan, EndSpan)`?

Comment: How many rows does the `spans` table contain? But I agree with Arioch: less than a second to return 1.5 million (or more) rows seems very ambitous

Comment: Also, if not for the wish to return out-of-spans IDs I would do reverse: `select s.SpnRecID, LIST( L.LstRecID ) from spans S, lists L where L.LstRecID between s.BeginSpan and s.EndSpan group by 1` and then do separation of IDs on client

Answer (score 0):

Does this query have better performance?

```
SELECT l.LstRecID,
       (SELECT MAX(s.BeginSpan)
        FROM Span s
        WHERE l.LstRecID >= s.BeginSpan
       ) as SpnRecID
FROM List l ;
```

You want an index on `Span(BeginSpan desc)`.  This might be easier to optimize.

I doesn't quite get what you want.  But, if this has acceptable performance, then what you really want is just a `join` away.

Given your volume of data, I would be surprised if there is any way of getting results in less than a few seconds.

EDIT:

In your sample data, you have a match for the beginning of all the ranges.  If you can guarantee this, then try:

```
SELECT l.LstRecID,
       COALESCE(s.BeginSpan,
                MAX(s.BeginSpan) OVER (ORDER BY l.LstRecID)
               ) as BeginSpan
FROM List l LEFT JOIN
     Span s
     ON l.LstRecID = s.BeginSpan;
```

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff.  The performance is just as slow as the BETWEEN query I have been using.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the result set I want, meaning, all the fields included, for every row, and blanks for where there is no span, and the results back in 75 milliseconds (one tenth the maximum time allowed, by limiting the size of (rows returned from) the span table in the Span table sub-select.

```
SELECT
  ...list and span fields you want to see...
FROM
  (SELECT ..list fields that match above.. FROM list table WHERE LstRecID BETWEEN your low limit AND your high limit) AS your list alias
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
      ... your span fields that match above ...
      FROM span table s
      WHERE
        (s.span low limit >= your same low limit) AND 
        (s.span high limit <= your same high limit) AS s
    ON (LstRecID BETWEEN s.BeginSpan AND s.EndSpan)
ORDER BY List.LstRecID
```

Comment: show `query plans` for all your three queries please

Comment: For clarification, I'm not pulling 1.2 million rows.  I'm only pulling a subset that will never contain more than 1440 rows.  The above solutions works.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add column `span_id` to the `lists` table, make it `foreign key` to the `spans` table and add `check constraint` that it would suffice the `between` condition.
2. Add `after update or insert or delete` trigger upon `spans` table and update rows in `lists` affected by every change in `spans` further on
3. do one time initial population of the newly added column by that "15 minutes" request